# What does OP mean

Tags: support

I'm relatively new to the site and I am sure this is addressed in the readme sections. I've come to realize that lots of people on here use the computer. I use my phone on a web browser. I can't find what OP means. There are many other things that I can't figure out but that one has absorbed me as of late.

Comment: Related: [Does OP mean “original poster” or “original post”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424366/does-op-mean-original-poster-or-original-post)

Comment: Thank you so much seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"OP" stands for "Original Poster". It's used most often to refer to the asker of a question, as in "We need more clarification from the OP to answer this question".

See also: [What does OP mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean)